# How to setup Python directory structure for Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python project I'm working on and am trying to implement tests with pytest and Jenkins.

My directory structure is like this:

```
project/
  src/
    __init__.py
    hello.py
    input.py
    person.py
  test/
    test_hello.py
```

When I run pytest from the project directory it works fine. But when I use Jenkins I keep getting the following error:

```
[-1_10-finish-basic-ci-setup-IIB3G6YENVYIQDST5MPMDBNVOZLYD6VSLP5ZCT6VUVQSNZJKGYEA] Running shell script
+ python src/hello.py true
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import src.person as person
ImportError: No module named 'src'
```

I run Jenkins inside a docker container and it spins up another docker container for testing my project. Can anyone please clue me in to how I can get it to recognize the src directory for running the test?

Comment: Maybe printing `os.getcwd()` from Jenkins and your project dir will help you debug this problem.

Comment: So I can see that the location of the project is `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/-1_10-finish-basic-ci-setup-IIB3G6YENVYIQDST5MPMDBNVOZLYD6VSLP5ZCT6VUVQSNZJKGYEA` but how do I get Jenkins to see the src directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've identified your problem correctly (and I hope you already googled this error), but I bumped into a very similar exception when I tried to run my python scripts with cron.

My workaround is to add this at the very beginning of the file. So when you do `python main.py` **the first** thing is running this. After `sys.path...` you import other modules. It basically appends working directory to pythonpath, so Python sees from where to run it. There're a few alternative solutions. This is ugly but it's very portable and you only need copypasting.

```
import sys, os

def get_abs_dir_for_module(*args):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), *args)

repo_dir = get_abs_dir_for_module("..", "..")
sys.path.append(repo_dir)
```

You need to pass a certain amount `".."` to this function. Play around and let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked with a single ".."! The weirdest thing is that my code always worked locally, just not in the container that was spun up my Jenkins. Everything I was able to find with a google search always seemed to refer to just a regular program, not one being run in a container that I had no access to.